# S3FS produce PDO exception

Tags: 7

I have a batch job that uploads articles to Drupal using the S3FS module. I come across this error and I am not sure how to fix this. Is there a way to fix this issue? I am using Drupal 7.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Drupal is trying to insert the file into its managed system with a record that already exists. It could be a bug. If you can consistently create the same error, you should report it to the module maintainer.

Comment: oh no. the module maintainer is no longer maintaining the s3fs module for drupal 7

Comment: Are you moving from a case sensitive filesystem to a case insensitive DB collation? That could cause duplicates